High school test question. Does the exercise have a mistake?
Knowing that   $\log_{b}8=c, \log_{a}81=a, a^{c}=27$,
find   $b^a$.
It seems to me, that the second given logarithmic equation cannot make sense? Am I missing something or the exercise had a mistake in formulation?

The second equation on its own is not wrong, it has the solution $81 = a^a$.

$$\log_a{81}=a \implies \log_a{27} = \frac{3}{4}a \implies c=\frac{3}{4}a$$
$$b^a=8^\frac{a}{c}=8^\frac{4}{3}=16$$

We are given
$$b^c=8 \tag1$$
$$a^a=81 \tag2$$
$$a^c=27 \tag3$$
Take (2) divided by (3):
$$a^{a-c}=3 \tag*{}$$
$$a^{a(1-\frac{c}{a})}=3 \tag*{}$$
$$81^{(1-\frac{c}{a})}=3 \tag*{}$$
$$3^{4(1-\frac{c}{a})}=3^1 \tag*{}$$
$$\frac{c}{a}=\frac34 \tag*{}$$
So now we have
$$b^a=b^{c(\frac{a}{c})}=8^{\frac43}=16 \tag*{}$$

The second equation can be rewritten as $81=a^a$ which has a solution. Indeed, since $y=x^x $ is increasing if $x>1$, and $3^3<81<4^4 $, it follows that $3<a<4 $. With that said, this does seem like a fairly tough question for high school.

The question isn't tough, because it asks to find the value of $b^a$, not $a$.

I suppose it''s country dependent, but I doubt very many American high school students (in precalculus say) could answer the question. In any case, I wasn't attempting to answer the test question; I was answering the OP's question.
